# c# - Reference path of image in resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a resource file (Example.resx) in my solution and it contains an image (pic.png). I also have a razor view (.cshtml) file that I am building dynamically. Here I have to give the reference of the pic.png image path from the resource.

> img src = 'path of the image from the resource'

Any way this can be done ?

Comment: Doesn't Example.pic work?

Comment: nope. just adding the name doesn't work

Comment: Can you post some code to show how you're trying to use the reference? What error(s) do you get?